# Web Scotty: file not found while serving static files

Tags: haskell, haskell-wai

This must be something really stupid. I just started playing with scotty and cannot get the static content served correctly.

```
import Network.HTTP.Types
import Web.Scotty
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Monoid (mconcat)
import Data.Aeson (object, (.=))
import Network.Wai.Middleware.Static

main = scotty 3000 $ do
  middleware $ staticPolicy (noDots >-> addBase "static")
  get "/" $ file "index.html"
```

Pretty simple. That's what you find in a couple of scotty tutorials. But it does not work for some reason. Accessing via '/' in the browser gives me the 'file not found' thing.
If I type '/index.html' at the browser - it works. But it is wrong! I want it to be accessible via '/' but not '/index.html'. It disregards the root and picks up the html file directly. How can I serve index.html via '/' root? There is not much info around and a couple tutorials that I found point to the above example or similar which does not work as expected.

I tried setting the headers to 'text/html' and what not ... No luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I type '/index.html' at the browser - it works. But it is wrong! I want it to be accessible via '/' but not '/index.html'.

But that's exactly what the [`staticPolicy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-middleware-static-0.5.0.0/docs/Network-Wai-Middleware-Static.html) middleware is for! Whenever a request matches a policy (in this case files in ./static/), it will be filtered by `staticPolicy`. If you don't want that behavior, remove the middleware.

> Accessing via '/' in the browser gives me the 'file not found' thing.

Because the middlware action doesn't set the relative path for the following commands. You need to give the full path for [`file`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.7.1/docs/Web-Scotty.html#v%3afile):

```
main = scotty 3000 $ do
  get "/" $ file "./static/index.html"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, if I understand it correctly, the 'file' function takes a file path relative to the current working directory and has nothing to do with the middleware exposed static directory, right? It is a bit confusing as it looks like I don't need the middleware to serve static html files whereas the few scotty examples on the net make you think otherwise. It seems that middleware static policy is only needed to expose css and javascript  files not the actual html files.

Comment: well the middleware will be useful when you don't want a explicit route for each of your files